# Windows 10 unattend.xml Disk Configuration Problem

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2016, wds, unattend-file

I have some troubles with my answer file. The file works exept the "Disk Configuration" part.
The Dialog popups every time even when i set the Value WillShowUI to "Never". I already tried so many examples from the internet, but none of them worked.

What's the Problem with my file? Is there any log file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                <UILanguage>de-DE</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>de-DE</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>de-DE</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguageFallback>de-DE</UILanguageFallback>
            <UILanguage>de-DE</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>de-DE</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <WindowsDeploymentServices>
                <Login>
                    <Credentials>
                        <Domain>domain.local</Domain>
                        <Password>MySecretPassword</Password>
                        <Username>Administrator</Username>
                    </Credentials>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                </Login>
                <ImageSelection>
                    <InstallImage>
                        <Filename>install.wim</Filename>
                        <ImageName>Windows 10 Education</ImageName>
                        <ImageGroup>Windows 10</ImageGroup>
                    </InstallImage>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                </ImageSelection>
            </WindowsDeploymentServices>
            <EnableFirewall>false</EnableFirewall>
            <EnableNetwork>false</EnableNetwork>
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Extend>false</Extend>
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Size>500</Size>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Extend>false</Extend>
                            <Size>100</Size>
                            <Type>EFI</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Extend>false</Extend>
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <Size>128</Size>
                            <Type>MSR</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>WinRE</Label>
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <TypeID>DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC</TypeID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Format>FAT32</Format>
                            <Label>System</Label>
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>Windows</Label>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                            <Active>true</Active>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                </Disk>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                    <Key>YNMGQ-8RYV3-4PGQ3-C8XTP-7CFBY</Key>
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <FullName>My Name</FullName>
                <Organization>MyCompany</Organization>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:d:/win10edu/install.wim#Windows 10 Education" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Comment: There's a folder under \Windows called \Panther. It contains a number of log files that describe issues encountered during setup. In winpe it will be on the x: drive and once you get to the post-deployment phase, it will be on the c: drive. I expect (but am not sure) that the x: drive files get copied to c:. There are separate logs for pre-image device gathering, errors, and actions.

Comment: Partition 4 is kind of a surprise. Could be there isn't a partition 4?

Comment: @Clay Thank you, i figured out what the problem was. the logfile was very helpful :)
And yes the Partition 1 was useless. now i have: 100 EFI, 128 MSR, remaining Primary

Comment: @ThisIsSuperman Please post your corrected unattend.xml as an answer!